# Using networkx with multiple dummy variables

Tags: python, networkx, dummy-variable

I am trying to learn networkx and have run into an issue.

I have a dataset that has individuals and multiple columns of dummy variables.

I am trying to have each individual as a node and each dummy variable as a node with edges that connect individuals to each dummy variable they have a 1 for.

Code I have:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, "NAME", dummy_variables)
nx.draw_shell(G, with_labels=True)
```

where dummy_variables is a list containing the dummy variables from the dataframe I am interested in

Here is a sample of the dataframe I am working with:
[dummy variable dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgsEf.png)

Where HSSAFETYX and other variables are dummy variables. Name is the individual.

What I want to see is each row represented by a node with edges connecting them to the dummy variables they have a 1 for.

Comment: you mean something like an [adjacency matrix](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_adjacency.html) ? [adjacency matrix definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Agreed.  Please provide a sample of the dataframe.

Comment: Adding now, should've included that originally.